# How to convert a single row into multiple on Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a table with separate rows in which every single row contains lots of English and their Turkish equivalents.
Each row has lots of Turkish sentences on the right cell and each Turkish sentence has its own English equivalent written right in front of it on the left cell. Hence, each row includes two cells; the right cell contains say five Turkish sentences and the left cell contains five English corresponding equivalents in it.
Now, I need to divide each row into separate rows each containing the Turkish and its English equivalent separately.
Can Microsoft Word do this through a trick or I need to insert separate rows and move the content manually?
I'm well aware that I can also use the word's pencil, but the problems are:

1. the table is too huge.
2. it can cause some mistakes.

To illustrate it, let me clarify my intention by two images:

I need the Word to change the following row:

[image: Same row]

into the following one automatically;

[image: separate rows]

I am wondering how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

First things first: Backup your valuable file before running this VBA macro.

You haven't tagged your question with the 'VBA' tag. If you're ok with that, please add this tag to the OP.

**EDIT:** added a new version of the first posted code to handle Paragraphs, preserving text formats (size, color, etc).

Also added:

1. checking for handle only tables that have exactly 2 columns.
2. a replacement of ^p in each new cell.

The new version:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnSplitCellsInNewTableRows()
    Dim oTables As Word.Tables 'all document tables
    Dim oTable As Word.Table ' each document table
    Dim intLenOldLines As Integer
    Dim intLenNewLines As Integer
    Dim oLeftPars As Word.Paragraphs 'Paragraphs on the left cell
    Dim oRightPars As Word.Paragraphs 'Paragraphs on the right cell
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim intTable As Integer
    Dim intTableRow As Integer
    Dim intTableRows As Integer
    Dim intTablesCount As Integer
    Dim oLeftPar As Word.Paragraph 'unique (left) paragraph to work with
    Dim oRightPar As Word.Paragraph 'unique (right) paragraph to work with
    Dim oTableRange As Word.Range 'used to Find/Replace ^p

    Set oTables = ThisDocument.Tables
    intTablesCount = oTables.Count
    
    For intTable = 1 To intTablesCount
        Set oTable = oTables(intTable)
        If oTable.Columns.Count <> 2 Then
            MsgBox "A table with " & oTable.Columns.Count & " was discharged."
            GoTo lblNextTable
        End If
        intTableRows = oTable.Rows.Count
        For intRow = 1 To intTableRows
            intLenOldLines = Len(oTable.Rows(intRow).Cells(1).Range.Text)
            intLenNewLines = Len(VBA.Replace(oTable.Rows(intRow).Cells(1).Range.Text, Chr(13), ""))
            
            'compare the amount of chr(13) ocurrences
            'each one determine a new inner line on the cell text, except for the last one.
            If intLenOldLines > intLenNewLines + 1 Then
                Set oLeftPars = oTable.Rows(intRow).Cells(1).Range.Paragraphs
                Set oRightPars = oTable.Rows(intRow).Cells(2).Range.Paragraphs
                oTable.Rows(intRow).Cells.Split (intLenOldLines - intLenNewLines) + 1, 1

                For intTableRow = oTable.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
                    Set oLeftPar = oLeftPars(intTableRow - 1)
                    Set oRightPar = oRightPars(intTableRow - 1)
                    oTable.Rows(intTableRow).Cells(1).Range.FormattedText = oLeftPar.Range.FormattedText
                    oTable.Rows(intTableRow).Cells(2).Range.FormattedText = oRightPar.Range.FormattedText

                Next

            End If
            ThisDocument.Save
            oTable.Rows(1).Delete ' the original row
            
            'this piece of code strips out ^p on each new cell
            oTable.Select
            Set oTableRange = oTable.Range
            With oTableRange.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "^p"
                With .Replacement
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = ""
                End With
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, _
                    Format:=True, MatchCase:=True, _
                    MatchWholeWord:=True
            End With

            ThisDocument.Save
        Next
        
lblNextTable:
    Next
    
    DoEvents
    MsgBox "Done."

End Sub
```

The old version, works with pure text (without formatting elements):

The VBA macro below takes all existing Tables in the document and, according to the images you posted, these tables will have their single rows divided into (in the example) 5 rows. Each inner row of the cell's text range (which was created by an 'Enter' = Chr(13)) will be filled in the new rows, except the first, which will remain in the existing cell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnSplitCellsInNewTableRows()
    Dim oTables As Word.Tables
    Dim oTable As Word.Table
    Dim oRow As Word.Row
    Dim oSplittedRow As Word.Row
    Dim arrLeftInnerLines() As String
    Dim arrRightInnerLines() As String
    Dim intLenOldLines As Integer
    Dim intLenNewLines As Integer
    Dim intLine As Integer
    
    Set oTables = ThisDocument.Tables

    For Each oTable In oTables
        For Each oRow In oTable.Rows
            intLenOldLines = Len(oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text)
            intLenNewLines = Len(VBA.Replace(oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text, Chr(13), ""))
            
            'compare the amount of chr(13) ocurrences
            'each one detrmine a new inner line on the cell text, except the last one.
            If intLenOldLines > intLenNewLines + 1 Then
                'loading each inner line on an array
                'notice that Word has it's own Split function - we don't want it now
                arrLeftInnerLines = VBA.Split(oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text, Chr(13))
                arrRightInnerLines = VBA.Split(oRow.Cells(2).Range.Text, Chr(13))
                oRow.Cells.Split (intLenOldLines - intLenNewLines), 1
                
                For Each oSplittedRow In oTable.Rows
                    oSplittedRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = arrLeftInnerLines(intLine)
                    oSplittedRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = arrRightInnerLines(intLine)
                    intLine = intLine + 1
                    If intLine = UBound(arrLeftInnerLines) Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                
            End If
            
        Next
    Next
    
MsgBox "Done."

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks good. Note that formatting will be lost if there is any direct font formatting (like the red in the screenshot).

Comment: Thank you very much @ALeXcel. Just, I am not that familiar with macros. May I ask you to do me another favor and let me know how shall I run it on MS-word 2016? After the execution, I will let you know about the result and any further questions. Thank you again.

Comment: I'll post another version of this code to handle paragraphs, which will preserve all the text with their formats for the new cells, as @CharlesKenyon noticed in his comment. Then I will explain how to do it.

Comment: @A-friend I posted the new version. If you don't know how /where to put the code we may continue to discuss that in a chat

Comment: Thank you @ALeXceL. Here is the link to the chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138925/how-to-use-a-macro-on-ms-word

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I've saved the URL in case I run into the issue in the future.